# AEM Inherited Component Dialog Fields Ordering

Tags: aem

In AEM, When I created a dialog which inherit from another dialog I have seen that sometimes the order of the nodes doesn't correspond to the order in which the fields are rendered in the dialog.

Is there a way in which we can specify exactly where a field should be rendered in component dialog?

Answer (score 3):

We can add **sling:orderBefore** attribute to component dialog field.

Syntax: sling:orderBefore=<--Node-Name-->

Ex: sling:orderBefore="parentPage"

Here parentPage is input field node, Now when you apply **sling:orderBefore** attribute, then that field will show top of parent page input field.

Thanks for reading.